# How to override virtual method present in inherited Nested Classes

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, nested

How to override a virtual method which is in  inherited nested classes?
Code Snippet:

```
class A
{
  public:
  virtual void foo();
};

class B
{
  public:
  class C: public A
  {};
};

class D: public B
{
    //How to override foo()`enter code here` method of class A here in class D?
}
```

Comment: Please clarify. There is no relationship between `C` and `B` or between `B` and `A`. Since `D` does not inherit `foo`, there is nothing for you to override.

Comment: Hi, Class C (which is derived from Class A) is an inner class to Class B. And Class D is derived from Class B. There is an inner and outer class and inheritance mix

Comment: Perhaps you're familiar with Java, where "inner" (or "nested") classes have a special relationship to the surrounding class, but C++ is not Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested classes are, for the most part, behaving exactly as if they were defined outside the class they are nested in.

The only differences relate to name lookup, accessibility and template specialization.

In particular, there is no inheritance relationship between a nested class and its enclosing class.

In your example

```
class B
{
  public:
  class C: public A
  {};
};
```

is (except for how `C`'s name can be found) equal to:

```
class B
{
};

class C: public A
{
};
```

There is no inheritance relationship between `C` and `B` and consequently neither between `D` and `A`. `D` and `A` are not part of the same class hierarchy.

Therefore it doesn't make sense to have `D` override a member function of `A`.